# fade in all divs of a page. once the content of the divs is loaded

Tags: jquery, fade, html, loaded

Sorry, Ill try simplify my question. Basically, when a user goes to a page...all the divs on the page and the content of the div fade in. Once loaded. I was thinking maybe something like:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
  $('#div').load(function () { 
    $(this).fadeIn(4000); 
  });
});
```

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will do what you need:

```
$(function() { // execute when DOM Ready:
  $("#div").load("someOtherFile.html", function() { 
    $(this).fadeIn(4000);
  }).hide();
});
```

Comment: I like your thinking but this maybe to complex. As im doing a shopping cart site with lots of pages. I would prefer a nice tidy script the lives in the head of every page of the site. So when any page is viewed the contents of the site fades in once loaded. .

Answer (score 0):

So you're not loading in any dynamic content, right? Have you tried, simply:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
   $('#div').fadeIn(4000);
});
```

$(window).load shouldn't fire until the whole page is loaded anyway--you shouldn't need to test again for the div/img. Doing so might be leading to some weirdness. You want this placed *outside of* $(document).ready(). See: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: tried your code.
$(window).load(function(){ 
   $('#div').fadeIn(4000);
});

it did not work for some reason. But i had success with

                $(document).ready(function() {  
                 $("#panel-two").fadeIn("3000");
                });

which loads in individual divs. as long as they are set to display none. So i have quite a fair bit of code in my head due to this method but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this was so simple it was overlooked, but to at least clarify the first code posting for others, the line:

$('#div').fadeIn(4000); 
Would only work on .
It may or may not work on descendante tags, depending upon their properties.

if you selected 
$('div').fadeIn(4000); 
that would perform the function on all div tags at once. And

$('.div').fadeIn(4000);
Would work on all objects with a class named 'div:

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

James is correct, change your code to:

```
$(window).load(function(){ 
   $('div').fadeIn(4000);
});
```

using `$('#div')` only selects elements with an id of 'div'